Why use Thread Control Blocks (TCB) Instead of Kernel stack for saving thread info?
Some Background
I have been studying operating systems and I am currently learning about system calls and how they are handled using interrupts. The course I am following (Berkly CS 162) Shows that each thread has a corresponding stack in the kernel that is used when executing privileged stuff like system calls.
Cause of Confusion
The following illustration shows that the interrupt causes the user stack stack pointer to be saved on the kernel stack along with the PC. The interrupt handler (in this case a sys call) then stores all other registers on the kernel stack.
Illustration from CS 162 Lecutre
My Question is as follows
If all the above info is stored into the kernel stack corresponding to the user stack, why do we save stuff in the TCB? As I see it, all info needed for a full execution context (registers, user stack, kernel stack) is there on the kernel stack? Is it a matter of convenience and being able to put the TCBs in a nice data structure for the scheduler or is there something I am missing.
I tried looking on the internet for answers but didn't find any. I then used AI but its answer doesn't seem to be based on a source it can cite so here I am turning to you nice people hoping for you to make me a little smarter.

After servicing an interrupt, a kernel typically will schedule the highest-priority thread/task that is ready to execute (rather than the thread that was interrupted & suspended).

@sawdust Thanks for the clarification but I am still lost in regards to the question I was asking. can you help me with the question?

@Apollo11 The answer is in your question. "why do we save stuff in the TCB?" Because there's stuff to save beyond execution context. Whole lot of stuff related to the thread, and it needs to go somethere, and it makes sense to put it all together in OOP fashion. FPU registers, scheduling data, signal data, locks stuff, statistics, debugging info, stacks location and heaps more.

Saving the thread's state on the stack would mean that the kernel would have to resume that thread after the interrupt. By saving its state in the TCB, that interrupted thread is now effectively suspended. The kernel is then free to select any run-able thread.

There is usually an separate interrupt stack because previous process might not become the active process after servicing the interrupt.
The hardware interrupt saves a small number of registers (not all). If the interrupt handler needs to use more registers, it has to save them on the stack and pop them at the end.
An interrupt handler will typically call the scheduler before returning.
You would need to save registers in a context block only if the context were to be switched by the scheduler.
If an interrupt returns to the same process, the only registers the typically saved are PC, SP, R0, R1 and the processor status register (varies by system).
The slide you have confuses interrupt handling with system service call handling.
